# Scala case class, conditional Copy

Tags: scala

I've defined a case class and a value:

```
scala> case class N(a:Int, b:Int)
defined class N

scala> val nnn = N(2,3)
nnn: N = N(2,3)
```

I would like to modify a field based on an optional value, *t1* and *t2* with type Option[Int], this is what i did:

```
val nnn1 = t1.map( x => nnn.copy( a = x)).getOrElse(nnn)
val nnn2 = t2.map( x => nnn1.copy( b = x)).getOrElse(nnn1)
```

Theres a Lens/Monocle/Scalaz way to do it generic?

Comment: How about `t1.fold(nnn)(a1 => nnn.copy(a = a1))`

Comment: Looks quite simple without lenses `nnn.copy(a = t1.getOrElse(nnn.a), b = t2.getOrElse(nnn.b))`

Comment: Looks nice! :) I like best the second option, it really simple.

Comment: Why not write it as a proper answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good approach colud be

```
def someF(i:Int) = // a great computation with i :)

val na = t1.map(someF).getOrElse(nnn.a)

val newnnn = nnn.copy(a = na, b = t2.getOrElse(nnn.b))
```

In a case where you have to apply **someF** to **t1** is probably a good idea separate it.
No lens for you.